# Help With Understanding a Specific Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working through the MIT 18.02 2007 Multivariate Calc class right now, and I don't understand a derivative they use in their answer key.

Specifically, given $T = \frac{-a\sin tI +a\cos tJ + bK}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$, where I, J, K are *x*, *y*, *z* components, we are asked to find $\frac{dT}{dt}$.  Most likely I am just dumb, but I get $-a\cos tI - a\sin tJ$, whereas the answer key tells me that I should have $\frac{-a\sin tI + a\cos tJ}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}}$.  I would appreciate any help understanding my errors.

Comment: Give us the context of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ term is a constant multiplied by the expression. The derivative of $cf(t)$, where c is a constant is $cf'(t)$.

I don't agree with the answer key (if you typed it in correctly).

I get the derivative as $\frac{-a\cos tI - a\sin t J}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: Ah, right, so kind of dumb.  But nonetheless, shouldn't $\frac{d}{dt}-a\sin tI = -a \cos tI$?

Comment: Yes, it should. See my edit. Of course, I could be dumb too. :) So let's see if someone else comes to post.

Comment: Thanks, at least I feel a little bit better :)